# Android - play audio when locking and. unlocking screen

Tags: android, audio, android-studio

I am new on Android Studio. I am currently building an app that allows you to play music when you're locking or unlocking your phone screen. It's similar to a media player, but it plays music when you're locking and unlocking your phone.

The idea of this app is to read your phone's sdCard and fetch the music files. After that, you choose the music that you want to set as your lock/unlock sound.

I already passed the file from the music list back to the mainActivity (not sure if I'm doing it right or not though).

My problem right now: setting the lock and unlock screen to play the chosen music when user click the confirm button.

Here's my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public  void ConfirmMessage(View view){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sound has been set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void GetMusicListLock(View view) {

    Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);
    final int resultLock=1;
    startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent, resultLock);

}

public void GetMusicListUnlock(View view) {

    Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);
    final int resultUnlock=2;
    startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent, resultUnlock);

}

@Override
//get result from the chosen music
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    TextView lockMusic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LocktextView);
    TextView unlockMusic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UnlocktextView);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String chosenLockMusic = data.getStringExtra("dataSend");

        lockMusic.setText(chosenLockMusic);

        String lName = data.getStringExtra("lname");
        File file = new File(lName);
        Toast.makeText(this, file.getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if(requestCode==2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        String chosenUnlockMusic = data.getStringExtra("dataSend");

        unlockMusic.setText(chosenUnlockMusic);

        String lName = data.getStringExtra("lname");
        File file = new File(lName);
        Toast.makeText(this, file.getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

SecondScreen (Music ListView)

```
public class SecondScreen extends Activity {
ListView lv;
String  [] items;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.music_layout);

    Intent activityThatCalled = getIntent();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMusicList);

    //Array for finding Music File
    ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

    //For storing the music names
    items = new String[mySongs.size()];

    //Show music names
    for(int i =0; i<mySongs.size(); i++){
        //toast(mySongs.get(i).getName().toString());
        items[i]= (mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","").replace(".wav",""));

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.song_layout, R.id.textView, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);

    //Listener for when the music is chosen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String data_send = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

            File file = new File(filepath);
            File f2= new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
            String path = f2.getAbsolutePath();

            Intent goingBack = new Intent();
            goingBack.putExtra("dataSend", data_send).putExtra("lname", path);


            setResult(RESULT_OK, goingBack);

            finish();
        }
    });
}


//function for findSongs
public ArrayList<File>findSongs(File root){

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for(File singleFile : files){
        if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
        }
        else{
            if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
                al.add(singleFile);

            }

        }
    }
    return al;
}

//  public void toast(String text){
//    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//}

}
```

LockScreenService

```
public class LockScreenService extends Service {

BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate() {

    //Start listening for the Screen On, Screen Off, and Boot completed actions
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);

    //Set up a receiver to listen for the Intents in this Service
    receiver = new LockScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

LockScreenReceiver. I think this is where I set my lock and unlock screen sound? But I don't have any idea how. I read that you can use shared preferences, but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"))
    {

    }
    else if (intent.equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"))
    {

    }
}

}
```

For more indepth info, here's the link to my source code. https://github.com/PiersonLeo94/Lock_Screen_Sound

Application that does similar function to what I want to build.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.screensound.ron.screensound&hl=en

Thanks.